# Insert string into other string

Tags: php

is there any function to insert string1 into another string2 if known particular insert place of string2. For example I have HTML code about 2000 chars long. And at 1000 char I want to insert other string which is 200 chars length.

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: there is a lot of ways. if you could be do kind to provide us with certain example of both your texts and circumstances, you will get way better answer

Comment: *(related)* [find and replace keywords by hyperlinks in an html fragment, via php dom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151064/find-and-replace-keywords-by-hyperlinks-in-an-html-fragment-via-php-dom/3151554#3151554)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
$newstr = substr($str, 0, 1000) . $insert . substr($str, 1000)
```

Made into a function

```
function insertAt($str, $position, $toInsert) {
    return substr($str, 0, $position) . $toInsert . substr($str, $pos)
}
```

Comment: What if  `$insert` breaks a HTML tag at position 1000?

Comment: @Pekka I am assuming he/she knows exactly where things should be inserted.

Comment: In my case substr works pretty well. If talking about dom functions, so what function to use ? Maybe this one - DOMCharacterData::insertData( http://www.php.net/manual/en/domcharacterdata.insertdata.php ) ?

Answer (score 3):

```
substr($html, 0, 1000) . $newHtml . substr($html, 1000)
```

But actually, that sounds like a really fragile idea. You should rather use [DOM](http://www.php.net/dom) processing methods.

Answer (score 1):

use wildcards at the place you want to insert code

```
$html="<div>%%wildcard%%</div>"
```

and use str_replace

```
$new_html=str_replace('%%wildcard%%', 'i like cookies', $html);
```